# Flyway: How to support cleaning of multiple schemas with same lifecycle?

Tags: database, database-migration, flyway

Using DB migrations using Flyway with multiple schemas which have the same lifecycle, how can I achieve that they all get clean when I use flyway:clean?

Comment: Created an issue for that: http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for this has now been added to the 1.3.1 release!

Set the **flyway.schemas** property with the list of schemas you wish to manage, and your good to go!

Example:

```
flyway.schemas=schema1,schema2,schema3
```

mvn flyway:clean will now clean all 3 schemas.